# If $a^2+b^{2\ }=\ c^2$ what is the value of $a^2-b^{2\ }$ in terms of $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Math Olympiad Question:
>
> If $a^2+b^{2\ }=\ c^2$ what is the value of $a^2-b^{2\ }$ in terms of $c$?

I was solving some problems of the Indian National Mathematics Olympiad and I found  this problem to be very intriguing. At first look it looks pretty straight forward but this problem requires the solution to be in terms of $c$ only, meaning that if you have the value of c, put that in your solution and you should get the same value as $a^2-b^{2\ }$.

I tried simple algebra, trigonometry, geometry and pattern recognition but none of these methods were quite successful and could give a reasonable proof + solution.

My question is how to find the solution and prove this question? Is it possible to use Geometry and solve?

EDIT -
Sorry my bad, I think $a>b$ and $a$ and $b$ are integer values as in the starting of the exam it's written that all values will be integer and non-negative.

> FINAL EDIT:
> I think this question has been misprinted. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? I don't think $a^2 - b^2$ is well-defined because let's say $c = 10$ then we can have $a = 8$ and $b = 6$, so $a^2 - b^2 = 28$ but we can also have $a = 10$ and $b = 0$, so $a^2 - b^2 = 100$.

Comment: I have gotten till $a^2-b^2=\sqrt {c^2-2ab}\cdot \sqrt {c^2+2ab}$. I don't know if it possible to simplify this...

Comment: Why do you think $a^2-b^2$ is a function of $c$?  Even if you force $a$, $b$, and $c$ to be positive integers, $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and $a\geq b$, there are still multiple values of $a^2-b^2$.    For example, $(a,b)=(56,33)$ and $(a,b)=(63,16)$ gives $c=65$, but $a^2-b^2$ is not unique.

Comment: It means if you take some three values that work for the formula $a^2+b^{2\ }=\ c^2$ then the same three values should work for $a^2-b^{2\ }$ = $x$ where $x$ is your solution in terms of c.

Comment: Another example to consider $7^2+24^2=15^2+20^2=25^2$

Comment: Maybe the question isn't framed very straightforwardly .

Comment: @strangeindian Do you know which specific paper this problem is from? (year)

Comment: I think it's not an official paper as my coaching center gave this as a mixed paper of math Olympiad question of INMO. It maybe prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are essentially looking at points on a circle of radius $c$.

If $x=\arctan \left(\frac ba\right)$

then $a=c \cos x,\text{ } b= c\sin x$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$

while $a^2-b^2=c^2 (\cos^2 x- \sin^2 x)=c^2 \cos 2x$.

$\cos 2x$ can take any value between $-1$ and $+1$, and there are rational points on the circle arbitrarily close to any point you choose. So for appropriate choices of $a,b,c$ (even if restricted to integers) you will find the whole range of possibilities. Where you are on the circle depends on the angle $x$ and not the radius $c$.

Comment: I like this solution. Maybe it wasn't a misprint but required exponential thinking like this.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

Take, for example, the following:

$$
4^2+3^2 = 5^2+0^2 = \sqrt{21}^2+ 2^2 = 5^2
$$

but 
$$
4^2 - 3^2 = 7\\
5^2 - 0^2 =25\\
\sqrt{21}^2-2^2 = 17
$$

So the value of $a^2-b^2$ does not depend only on $c$.